# Moving dynamically created DIV by dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, draggable

I'm dynamically creating div elements using JavaScript, also there is a move icon in each div which user can use to drag/move div, here is my div creation code:

```
            var _body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        var _div = document.createElement('div');
        _div.style.width = "250px";
        _div.style.height = "150px";
        _div.style.position = "relative";
        _div.id = "div" + count.toString();

        var imgMove = document.createElement("img");
        imgMove.setAttribute("src", "boxmove.png");
        _div.appendChild(imgMove);
```

how can I use JQuery draggable() function to move my div when user drags move icon, any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `handle` option to `img` which will mean the image will be used as the drag handle.

```
_body.appendChild(_div);
$(_div).draggable({ handle: "img" });
```

The `handle` option is a selector to target an element within the container, so you can be more specific by giving the image a class name, which would be needed if you had multiple images in the div, but only wanted a certain image as the drag handler.

From the [docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-handle)

> handle
>
> If specified, restricts dragging from starting unless the mousedown occurs on the specified element(s). Only elements that descend from the draggable element are permitted.

Comment: thanks, it worked, but can you please explain 2nd part, i.e. how to distinguish between two images, how can I set a css selector here?

Comment: oh thanks, I think I got it! you helped me so much, but is there such a function for resizing the div? I used resizable() but it didn't work

Comment: Just give your image a class for example `myhandler` then use `{ handle: "img.myhandler" }`

Answer (score 1):

Here is quick solution for drag-and-drop:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function allowDrop(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev){
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));

}
</script>
```

This is the HTML markup:

```
<style type="text/css">
[ondragover] {width:200px;height:200px; outline: 1px solid #ccc}
[draggable] {width:48px;height:48px;background-color:#999; border:1px solid #eaeaea;position:relative}
[draggable]:hover {cursor:pointer}
</style>
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div id="div2"ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <div id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></div>
    <div id="drag2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></div>
    <div id="drag3" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></div>
    <div id="drag4" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></div>
</div>
```